# Watch other processes start event in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

Is there any way (except polling) to watch other processes start event in NodeJS?

I want to pop a notification when a user runs the black-listed apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a websocket for this. A websocket is a protocol which remains the connection with the user. After you then detect that they run a forbidden application you can emit a signal which then can create this notification.

[Socket.io](https://socket.io/)  is a convenient `NPM`  package for websockets.

Hopefully this helps!